# Angularjs templateUrl does not render properly in Flask/python3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, flask, components

Setup:

- Flask/Python3
- AngularJS==1.7

i have the following project structure:

```
- myapp/
   - static/
      - app/
         - my-nav/
             - my-nav.component.js
             - my-nav.module.js
             - my-nav.template.js
         - app.css
         - app-module.js
         - index.html
- main.py
```

The unsolved issue is that the rendering of the **templateUrl** property of the component does not work!

> Show *nothing* and *no error message* in console!

Follow the below javascript component code:

```js
'use strict';

// register navbar component, along with its associated controller and template
angular.
    module('myNav').
    component('myNav', {
    templateUrl: '/static/app/my-nav/my-nav.template.html',
    controller: function MyNavController($http) {
        var author = 'author';
        console.log(author);
    }
});
```

What's wrong? Which is the correct path of the templateUrl?

---

## Solved

*It was my terrible mistake*, the ng-app directive scope was put wrongly into **head** tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the relative path from your `index.html` file:

Change:

```
templateUrl: '/static/app/my-nav/my-nav.template.html',
```

To:

```
templateUrl: 'my-nav/my-nav.template.html',
```

Comment: @Ahmed.. i tryed also with the relative path but still not work... i still have the same problem.